# React Native iOS simulator only performs fetch on click

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

I have a weird bug in my simulator. iOS / React Native does a call, but it waits until I click inside the simulator to actually display the data (and show the result actions from Redux in my console.log).

Has anyone experienced this behaviour before?

Comment: Are you working with `ListView`s by any chance? I faced a similar problem where all the data was fetched, but only after starting the scroll up/down movement did the rows appear

Comment: Not in this particular view, it happens to every fetch I execute.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using remote JS debugging (in Chrome for example), try disabling it.

**Update:** Rather than disabling JS debugging completely, you can instead deactivate breakpoints and remove Pause on exceptions, which usually means you don't have to click to nudge the code to progress.

To do so in Chrome click the `Sources` tab in inspector, followed by the relevant file, then on the right ensure the two options are disabled. One looks like a bullet with a line through it (you want this to be blue), and the other looks like a pause icon in a circle (you want this to be grey).